# cant assign any modules to category layout in Opencart 2

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I have a Opencart 2.0.1.1 installed on my server with a few modules installed but I cant seem to assign them to the category layout.

for an example, I have a banner and I have assigned it to the category layout but it doesnt show. But when I assign it to any information page or home page it shows.

none of the a modules work for the category layout. There are no errors in the error log either

Can someone let me know what might causing this problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: From where, you have set modules for category layout ?

Comment: @zedBlackbeard im assigning through system->design->layout->category

Comment: Layout route and status (enable / disable ) of the module checked ? I have checked with featured product on category page. It is working Ref : http://awesomescreenshot.com/0325kkoz7f

Comment: are u using any theme or default one ?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with Version 2.3.0.2. Maybe you already solved it;  but in case anyone else needs a solution I found a workaround: 
Create a new Categories Layout to which you assign your modules. Next, assign your new layout to each category by overriding the standard layout of each of your categories with the one you just created. 
In case you need some directions, here's how to do this:
In the admin section go to Design > Layouts. Create a new layout for your category pages by clicking on the plus sign in the rop right of the screen (it says 'Add New' when you hover over it). 
The new screen will show a fresh layout; give it a unique name in the field 'Layout name'. 
Now click on the plus sign below the line that says 'Store' and 'Route'.  This creates two empty fields in which you can fill in your store and route. Select the name for your store (mine is simply 'default') and in the route field enter 'product/category' (without the quote marks). Now assign the modules of your choice in this new layout. When you are done save the layout by hitting the save button in the top of the screen.
The next step is that you assign your new categories layout to all your existing categories. 
Go to Catalog > Categories and open the first category on your list by hitting it's edit button. 
In the edit screen, go to the tab 'Design' and select your newly created layout in the dropdown list under 'Layout Override' . Hit the Save button and edit the next Category in the same manner. Go through the entire list and you are done. 
…That's it :)